# Upload a ZIP file using WWW::Mechanize module

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a `HTML` web page. It has 4 text boxes, 1 upload box and a submit button.

I have to pass the text box values through the Perl script using `WWW::Mechanize` and `Win32::IE::Mechanize` module

It is working fine.

But I don't know how to pass the zip file using `Win32::IE::Mechanize` module.

Is there any way to attach the zip file automatically in the HTML page using `WWW::Mechanize` module.

Thanks in advance.